# Installing Eclipse 3.6 and Tomcat 7

Tags: 11.04, eclipse, tomcat

I am a beginner with Ubuntu.  I've read many questions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to install Eclipse 3.6 and Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 11.04. I've tried many answers posted but still no use.

I want to install this software to do a JSP project. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're considering upgrading your Ubuntu to 11.10 soon, then you can just do this now - Oneiric has Eclipse 3.7 (not 3.6 though - but supposedly better, huh?) and Tomcat 7 in repositories. So you'll be able to install everything with

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse tomcat7
```

Alternatively, downloading any version of eclipse from its website and running it straight from the unpacked tarball works very well too - what exactly was the problem you spent 2 days on?

Comment: I was trying to install eclipse directly from eclipse.org using tarball installation. But every time I extract the folder I get either error saying binary files cannot be opened or no action. I am thinking of upgrading my ubuntu and solve this issue!!!

Comment: Are you having problem extracting the tarball or when trying to run eclipse? If the latter - can you start it from console to see what the errors are? Do you have Java installed?

Answer (score 2):

I *just* left a comment in another question about Eclipse. I would recommend not using the repositories, but just downloading it from [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads/), extracting it to somewhere in your home directory and creating a launcher for it.

- It has its own updater
- You can blissfully ignore the plugins in the repos too. Downloaded everything from within Eclipse and you'll be fine.
- You control what version you're running. If you *need* 3.6 you can have it.

As for Tomcat, just install the `tomcat7` package.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a similar question, however the next step after installing which was given by Sergey is configuring eclipse and tomcat to work together.

[This Stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447289/problem-creating-a-tomcat-6-server-in-eclipse-form-ubuntu) works even with tomcat7 so I thought it will be useful for anyone else who looking for the answer for Ubuntu.

On thing to note is that when you install tomcat from the repositories, the service is started automatically, so when developing you may want to stop the server first using

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```